# Ordenando resultados de relacionamento "ManyToManyField" com a mesma tabela em Django

Tags: python, django

Estou com o relacionamento Many to Many com a mesma tabela, e preciso ordenar o resultado com a mesma sequencia da criação.
ex: adiciono Django básico, Django intermediário, Django avançado;
Tem q aparece nessa sequencia na visualização.
Já tentei {% for req in course.requirements.all|dictsort:"id" %} na view, mas sem resultado. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda. Desde já agradeço. Obrigado...

**model.py:**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    requirements = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CourseContentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CourseContent

class CourseAdmin(AjaxSelectAdmin):
    list_display = ('name')
    search_fields = ['id', 'name']
    list_filter = ['created_at']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
    inlines = (CourseContentInline,)
    form = make_ajax_form(Course, {
        'requirements': 'courses',
    })

admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)
```

**view.py**

```
def details(request, slug):
course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
course_content = CourseContent.objects.filter(course=course)

context = {
    'course': course,
    'course_content': course_content,
}

return render(request, 'portal/courses/details.html', context)
```

**details.html**

```
<aside class="col-lg-3">
{% if course.requirements.count >= 1 %}
    <article class="content-info">
        <h2>Pré-Requisitos</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>
            {% for req in course.requirements.all %}
                - <a href="{% url 'portal_courses_details' req.slug %}">{{ req.name }}</a><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>

    </article>
{% endif %}
</aside>
```

**área admin**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**visualização**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema resolvido!!!**

O problema foi resolvido com o uso do pacote "[django-sortedm2m](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sortedm2m)". Dessa forma consegui ordenar o resultado de uma maneira simples e eficaz.

**instalação**

```
pip install django-sortedm2m
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sortedm2m',
]
```

**model.py**

```
from sortedm2m.fields import SortedManyToManyField

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    requirements = SortedManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**criar e rodar as migrations**

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Problema resolvido!!!